# How can I forward a response from another server (internal server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am writing an application to monitor my company's servers. The application uses an asp.net core web API. The application maintains a list of known servers. When a get request comes in, it will respond with its own status or the status of another server. In the case of a response from another server, I want to forward the response, https status codes and all. The other servers are internal so I cannot just issue an HTTP redirect.

Here's the method I am using now. I currently get an http status code 500 when i request another server name. The other server isn't currently up so I'd expect a 404 status code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
{
    if (Dns.GetHostName().Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return await GetThis();
    }

    var instanceUri = _context.InstanceUri(name);
    if (instanceUri == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(name);
    }
    var serverUrl = new Uri($"{instanceUri}{Url.Action(nameof(GetThis))}");
    var remoteRequest = new HttpClient()
    {
        BaseAddress = serverUrl
    }.GetAsync(serverUrl);
    await remoteRequest;
    //TODO: Handle errors and forward proper status codes
    return new ObjectResult(remoteRequest);
}
```

Here's the full controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Controller for getting server information.
/// </summary>
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ServerController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationGlobalContext _context;

    public ServerController(ApplicationGlobalContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of server names
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return _context.InstanceNames;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets status of this server
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetThis()
    {
        var computerInfo = new ComputerInfo();
        var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        var hostAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(hostName);
        return new ObjectResult(new Server()
        {
            Name = hostName,
            IpAddresses = await hostAddresses,
            Memory = new Memory()
            {
                AvailablePhysicalMemory = computerInfo.AvailablePhysicalMemory,
                AvailableVirtualMemory = computerInfo.AvailableVirtualMemory,
                TotalPhysicalMemory = computerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory,
                TotalVirtualMemory = computerInfo.AvailableVirtualMemory,
            },
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a server by name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the server</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
    {
        if (Dns.GetHostName().Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return await GetThis();
        }

        var instanceUri = _context.InstanceUri(name);
        if (instanceUri == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(name);
        }
        var relUri = Url.Action(nameof(GetThis));
        var serverUrl = new Uri($"{instanceUri}{Url.Action(nameof(GetThis))}");
        var remoteRequest = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = serverUrl
        }.GetAsync(serverUrl);
        await remoteRequest;
        //TODO: Handle errors and forward proper status codes
        return new ObjectResult(remoteRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the HTTP 500 coming from ? can u trace it in fiddler is it even making it to the other box ?

Comment: @saj The http 500 exception is probably coming from the app's error handler as httpclient is throwing a `SocketException` because the host doesn't respond before some timeout. I suppose what I need to do is catch these exceptions and then just return `ControllerBase.NotFound`?

Comment: If the other server is not up yet HTTP 500 is what you should expect. HTTP404 means it was able to contact the other server, but couldn't find what was requested.

Comment: I envisioned it this way, the request to the external server was successful and it recognized the name parameter but it could not find the server the name refers to. So I guess httpclient won't give me a status code on a non response. I should perhaps catch its exceptions and return either 408 request timeout or 502 bad gateway.